# Mostrar items de una lista desde abajo hacia arriba en Android

Tags: android, android-listview

Tengo un listview personalizado en mi aplicación android, pero tengo una duda quiero saber como muestro los datos que agrego a dicha lista desde abajo hacia arriba como las apps de chat.

A continuación comparto mi código

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/blanco">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/lista_todos_mensajes" />

</LinearLayout>
```

item personalizado:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#c0303b47"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@mipmap/icono"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt_sms_nombre_ruta"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Nombre ruta"
                android:textColor="#fabd05"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:typeface="sans"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_sms_conductor"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Mensaje"
                    android:textColor="@color/blanco"
                    android:textSize="15sp"
                    android:typeface="sans" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txt_sms_hora"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                    android:text="Fecha y hora"
                    android:textColor="@color/blanco"
                    android:textSize="12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

y en mi activity hago lo siguiente:

```
adaptador = new Adaptador_mensajes_estudiante(this,datos);
lista_todos_mensajes.setAdapter(adaptador);
```

Adaptador:

```
public class Adaptador_mensajes_estudiante extends BaseAdapter {
    protected Activity activity;
    protected ArrayList<Datos_mensajes_estudiante> items;
    public Adaptador_mensajes_estudiante(Activity activity, ArrayList<Datos_mensajes_estudiante> items){
        this.activity = activity;
        this.items = items;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return items.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_mensaje_estudiante, null);
        }
        Datos_mensajes_estudiante datos_mensajes_estudiante = items.get(position);
        TextView txt_sms_nombre_ruta = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt_sms_nombre_ruta);
        TextView txt_sms_conductor = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt_sms_conductor);
        TextView txt_sms_hora = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txt_sms_hora);
        txt_sms_nombre_ruta.setText(datos_mensajes_estudiante.getNombre_ruta());
        txt_sms_conductor.setText(datos_mensajes_estudiante.getMensaje_conductor());
        txt_sms_hora.setText(datos_mensajes_estudiante.getHora_mensaje());
        return v;
    }
}
```

Ya intente colocar android:stackFromBottom="true" en mi listview y nada siempre los items se muestran de arriba hacia abajo

De antemano les agradezco

Comment: Creo que la opción no es modificar el adaptador pero si sus datos, ve la opción que sugiere FederHico, usando Collections.reverse(

Comment: @Jorgesys la idea es que cada dato que ingresa se presente al igual que el chat de whatsapp

Answer (score 1):

Deberías usar el método reverse:

```
adaptador = new Adaptador_mensajes_estudiante(this,datos);
lista_todos_mensajes.setAdapter(Collections.reverse(adaptador));
```

Si eso no funciona, en el código JAVA de tu adaptador retorna el reverse del mismo.

Otra posibilidad es insertar el último item en la posicion 0 mediante la sobrecarga `insert(T,int)` del método insert:

```
 insert("Nuevoelemento", 0)
```

Otra posible Aproximación es sobreescribir el metodo GetItem del Adaptador, para que retorne el último en vez del primero:

```
@Override
public Item getItem(int position) {
    return super.getItem(getCount() - position - 1);
}
```

Comment: donde ubico el metodo insert? con la primera opcion no se soluciono, la idea amigo es que cada nuevo dato que ingresa se muestre al final asi como whatsapp

Comment: Cuando insertas el elemento al adapter

Comment: creo que sobreescribir el getItem es la mas acertada

Comment: no amigo no funciona mi app es parecida a un chat la cual va recibiendo mensajes y por cada mensaje que va ingresando quiero q se muestre de abajo hacia arriba en la lista

Comment: comparte el codigo del adapter

Comment: ya ahora actualizo mi pregunta

Comment: yo estoy saliendo a almorzar, pero apenas vuelva lo veo, busca el GetItem y sobreescribelo

Comment: si lo cambie pero no sale jaja

Comment: En el constructor, cuando haces this.items = items;  no puedes hacer this.items = Collections.reverse(items) ?

Comment: no no puedo me sale un error

Answer (score 1):

Un poco tarde, pero bueno si a alguien le sirve :

```
    lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);
    Adaptador_mensajes_estudiante adapter = new Adaptador_mensajes_estudiante(this,datos);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setSelection(datos.size() - 1);  //Esta es la linea clave. Indicamos que el focus al listView se realize en el último elemento de este.
```

A mi me funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

Usa `Collections.reverse()` para cambiar el orden de los datos que alimentan tu Adapter:

```
//*** invierte el orden de los datos.
Collections.reverse(datos); 
//instancia Adapter
adaptador = new Adaptador_mensajes_estudiante(this, datos);
```